# Update all GTK and Qt applications' themes on the fly

Tags: linux, themes, gtk, qt

I use a tool called [`oomox`](https://github.com/themix-project/oomox) to generate GTK themes. After I generate the new theme, I would like to run a command that makes all currently open GTK applications use said new theme. I'm pretty sure desktop environments like GNOME have this functionality but I'm using a window manager. Is there any command, utility, or method of telling all currently open GTK applications to "refresh" their theme? I use some Qt applications and they use my GTK theme via `qt5-styleplugins`. I would also like to make these applications refresh to use the new theme.

To be clear, any applications I open after generating the theme already use it; I make the name the same and it replaces the old one. I would like a way specifically to update already open applications. Finally I would heavily prefer if I could do this from the command line but any solutions are appreciated.

BTW Antix Linux has this functionality. If it isn't possible on Arch Linux or on window managers please let me know.

OS: Arch Linux